# Delphi TTable.Exists fails on Paradox table even if database tables exist

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, paradox

When I create a table object (Table1) from scratch and assign the TableName property to an existing table on disk, the Table1.Exist function fails. I'm using Delphi2010 and it is a Paradox 7 table.

```
filename := ZipMaster1.DirEntry[i].FileName;
if Pos('.DB', UpperCase(filename)) > 0 then
begin
  Table1 := TTable.Create(FormArchiveFileSelector);
  Table1.TableName := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ExtractDir) + ExtractFileName(filename);
  if Table1.Exists then
    Table1.DeleteTable;
  Table1.Free;
end;
```

When I replace `Table1.Exists` with `FileExists(Table1.TableName)`, this returns true. Does anyone have any explanantion for this?

**Solution code**

Followed suggestions, below is some 'correct' sample code:

```
filename := 'C:\Temp\tables\XXX_1.db';
Table1.DatabaseName := ExtractFilePath(filename);
Table1.Tablename := ExtractFileName(filename);
if Table1.Exists then MessageDlg('Exists', mtInformation, [mbOK], 0)
else MessageDlg('Missing', mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
```

Note: Even setting `Table1.Tablename` to the full path and tablename while setting DatabaseName properly cause the Exists function to fail. TableName must be *without* the path, always.

Comment: Our product is a large (>1 million lines of code), badly designed system >10 years old. Limited nr of developers (i.e. budget) - you get the picture!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to separately set the DatabaseName and FileName.

```
Table1 := TTable.Create(whatever);
Table1.DatabaseName := ExtractDir;
Table1.TableName := ExtractFileName(filename);
```

(You should really get away from the BDE and Paradox files (as well as TTable). The BDE has been deprecated for more than a decade now, and may not ship in future versions of Delphi. There are serious issues with the latest versions of Windows as well.)

Comment: The problem is that the BDE uses DOS-based locking mechanisms (for lack of a better explanation) and these no longer work reliably now that the underlying OS, filesystem and connecting application are based on different assumptions.

Comment: Ok, I suspected something like that, will test quickly.

Comment: @Johan : Is this the reason that this specific function fails (if so can you explain) or just a general comment? Believe me, we are fully aware of the shortcomings of still using BDE etc!

Comment: @bosvos, the reason your approach failed is because the databasename in paradox is really an alias for `directory` in paradox speak. And the tablename is not allowed to have directory-elements in it, because all tables in a paradox database must be in the same directory. This is how paradox enforces that.

Comment: @Johan, right, that would make sense. Unfortunately it seems that it is not (or cannot) be enforced across all functions (e.g. 'Open'), which is what confused me in the first place. Thanks all for your replies.